# Python Tkinter - read the value inside the function with a pandas outside the function

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am working on opening csv file with tkinter. I have a function for importing csv data:

```py
def import_csv_data():

       global v
       csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
       v.set(csv_file_path)
       return csv_file_path
```

and for buttons:

```py
tkinter.Label(root, text='File Path').grid(row=0, column=0)

v = tkinter.StringVar()

entry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=v).grid(row=0, column=1)

tkinter.Button(root, text='Browse Data Set',command=import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)

tkinter.Button(root, text='Close',command=root.destroy).grid(row=1, column=1)

font_sizes = [15, 25]
```

I need to open the imported file in import_csv_data() function called csv_file_path. However, I can't get the value of csv_file_path. I write

```py
my_data = pd.read_csv(import_csv_data())
```

to read the return value for the csv file path but it runs twice in this case. How can I get the path without running twice?

Comment: Try `my_data = pd.read_csv(v.get())`? The problem I see is that, your calling the function twice. What you want to is, either assign it to a global variable or use `v.get() `. Or just get rid of the buttons?

Comment: Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).